# Asp.net ajax autocomplete inside jquery ui dialog not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Asp.net ajax autocomplete inside jquery ui dialog not working,
Please help

The autocomplete list appears behind the Jquery ui dialog

Update:
I tried following workaround but still it doesn't work

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="ACEVendor" runat="server" TargetControlID="DrplVendor"
    ServiceMethod="GetVendorforDrp" ServicePath="~/GRN/GRNService.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    UseContextKey="True" Enabled="True" OnClientShowing="clientShowing">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clientShowing(source, args) {
        $(source._popupBehavior._element.style.zIndex = 99999;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CompletionListCssClass property to the AutoCompleteExtender with the following style:

```
.AutoCompleteExtenderList
{
    z-index: n !important;
}
```

Where n is dialog's z-index + 3 (4002 by default)

Answer (score 0):

if you are use .net framework 3.5 then jquery will crash with Ajax.. you need to create object of jquery with noConflict.